# How to disable ripple effect in polymer paper elements?

Tags: cordova, polymer, material-design, paper-elements

I am writing a web app for mobile using `polymer` which will be packaged using `phonegap` to run on android device. I am using polymer `paper-tabs` and `core-animated-pages` to show a switching effect. On a device, everything works well except the `ripple effect` on tab touch. It makes the entire thing looks ugly and laggy. How do I disable the ripple effect in paper tabs (and eventually every other paper element) ?

I tried setting the `noink` property to `true` in source of paper-tabs as following, but it din't work.

```
 Polymer('paper-tabs', {

/**
 * If true, ink ripple effect is disabled.
 *
 * @attribute noink
 * @type boolean
 * @default false
 */
noink: true,
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `noink` attribute on the elements that have ripple effects to turn it off:

```
<paper-button noink>No ink!<paper-button>
<paper-tabs noink>...<paper-tabs>
```

AFAICT, the first may not work until the next Polymer release of paper-button. It does work in master however if you want to bleed on the edge.

Comment: Also looks like it's possible to style it with CSS if you'd rather disable ripples across all ui elements in a section:

`#no-ripple paper-ripple { color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }`

or page wide:

`html /deep/ paper-ripple { color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }`